# Show annotations in main project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have a library with methods to which I wrote annotations. Here is one method:

```
/**
     * Delete Connection.
     * Result is returned through callback.
     *
     * @param customerSecret - current Customer secret code
     * @param connectionSecret - secret code of the Connection which should be deleted if exist
     * @param callback - callback for request result
     */
    public void deleteConnection(String customerSecret,
                                 String connectionSecret,
                                 DeleteEntryResult callback) {
        new ConnectionDeleteConnector(callback).deleteConnection(customerSecret, connectionSecret);
    }
```

But when I use this method in my main project, I don't see this annotation:

```
public void deleteConnection(String customerSecret, String connectionSecret, DeleteEntryResult callback) {
    (new ConnectionDeleteConnector(callback)).deleteConnection(customerSecret, connectionSecret);
}
```

Q: How can I display my annotations in a project?

Comment: Copy paste it.  Or don 't, as it will fall out of sync with changes.  THe user should reference the base class version's.  With Javadoc there will automatically be a section for inherited functions and shoudl pick that up from the base class.  You should only put docs here if you want to comment on specific implementation details of this version.

Comment: @GabeSechan may be there is somewhere an example how to do it right? and in words not very still understand how it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved my problem with this [post](https://medium.com/@hamen/android-library-aar-and-javadoc-6859898cad28)

**Recipe is simple:**

Annotate methods to which you want to see annotations

Write task in `build.gradle` to choose which classes to document:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'

    include("**/SomeClass.java")
}
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

After that, rebuild your library and everything should work.